# Upload Image to Existing doc in Firebase/Firestore v9 with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am currently having trouble uploading an image/file to firestore. I have been stuck on this for hours now. I am using the latest version as well as the latest version of nextJS and reactJS. I am tried copying the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#web-version-9_3) but using both uploadString and uploadBytesResumable yield no success. I also tried various online tutorials. My rules are set in firestore such that anyone can read or write.

I can upload when there is no image selected in the `filePickerRef`/`imgFile`; however, when I include a file input along with my text input, only the text is uploaded. I am using a form with a button and an input to submit the text, when this is submitted, I check if there is a file uploaded (imgFile is a state that gets set when the file input tag is changed -- `filePickerRef.current.files[0]` should also have the file but neither work...), if there is, I attempt to upload the file to the document I just added the message and timestamp to (Note: this file is uploaded to a file input outside of the form and when the input changes, it calls `setImgFile(event.target.files[0])`. the input also has the prop `ref='filePickerRef'` which was generated by the `useRef()` hook).

The error I get is:

> FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)

with the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found."
  }
}
```

When I run the web tools debugger, I can see that both imgFile and `filePickerRef.current.files[0]` have the File object of the file I selected to be uploaded, but the upload still fails.

Here is my code below:

```
const uploadMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    // no text input
    if (!inputRef.current.value) return

    addDoc(collection(db, 'msgs'), {
        message: inputRef.current.value,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp()
    }).then(docRef => {
        if (imgFile) {
            //const file = filePickerRef.current.files[0]
            const file = imgFile

            // upload image
            const storafeRef = ref(storage, `msgs/${docRef.id}`)
            const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storafeRef, file)

            // note: imageToPost is state set by a file reader using readAsDataURL() when the file input changes
            //uploadString(storafeRef, imageToPost, 'data_url').then(() => console.log('submitted image!'))                

            uploadTask.on("state_changed", 
            snapshot => {
                const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100)
                setProgresspercent(progress)
            },
            error => {
                alert(error)
            },
            () => {
                getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(url => {
                    setDoc(doc(db, 'msgs', docRef.id), { url }, { merge: true })
                })
            })

            console.log('image uploaded.')

        } else {
            console.log('no image.')
        }

        console.log('Added doc: ', docRef.id)
    }).then(() => {
        inputRef.current.value = ''
        setImageToPost(null)
        setImgFile(null)
        filePickerRef.current.value = ''

        console.log('removed image.')
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    })
}
```

These are my firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're uploading an image to Cloud Storage through Firebase (a file storage service), not to Firestore (a document database). The error message also comes from Storage, and not from Firestore. So your Firestore security rules are likely not relevant to the problem. --- I also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as isolating this problem (for example: reproducing it without using Firestore at all) will make it more likely that someone can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am confused about this. Inside firebase, my documents are stored in the firestore database... I am using documents not files (addDoc, setDoc, updateDoc). Is there something I am doing wrong with this?

Comment: Edit: I think I undertsand what you mean now. For the image, I am uploading to the storage imported from my friebase.js and for the text I am using db from firebase.js. This is what all the tutorials say to do, I cannot find one that uses db for the images.